# Why a tag don't get animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to animate  with animate.css but it doesn't work.this is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('animated infinite pulse');
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Animate.css Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>
    <a  href='#hi'>Hello World</a>
  </h1>
  <p><a href="#bye">bye</a></p>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if i use another selector like h1 & p it works but why a doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The `a` tags are `inline` element so the animation won't work with it. Instead make them `inline-block` or apply the class to its parent since which are `block` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('animated infinite pulse');
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<h1>
    <a  href='#hi'>Hello World</a>
  </h1>
<p><a href="#bye">bye</a>
</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('animated infinite pulse');
  });
})
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<h1>
    <a  href='#hi'>Hello World</a>
  </h1>
<p><a href="#bye">bye</a>
</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags are displayed inline by default. You need to change the display property in order for the animation to work. I'd suggest using `inline-block`. I've provided an inline example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('animated infinite pulse');
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Animate.css Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>
    <a  href='#hi'>Hello World</a>
  </h1>
  <p><a href="#bye" style="display: inline-block;">bye</a></p>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the a tags to have a style of `inline-block`

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Updated Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('animated infinite pulse');
  });
})
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Animate.css Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <a  href='#hi'>Hello World</a>
  </h1>
  <p><a href="#bye">bye</a>
  </p>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```